# Why is NGINX's $request_uri empty?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using NGINX (v4.5.2) on a Kubernetes cluster, and I'm trying to configure it to redirect non-www URLs to the www equivalent. For example...

> https://example.com  ->  https://www.example.com
> https://example.com/about  ->  http://www.example.com/about

So this is what I've added to the annotations (I'll carry on using `example.com` as the URL host)...

```
annotations:
  ...
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    if ($host = 'example.com' ) {
      rewrite ^ https://www.$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

However, if I now navigate to `https://example.com` I get redirected to `https://www.`.

[The docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) say `$request_uri` contains ...

> full original request URI (with arguments)

... so why is `$request_uri` apparently empty in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request_uri` will contain the path with arguments. To get your desired redirect you probably want to use `$host$request_uri`.
For some examples of usage of `$request_uri` you can search it on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ to see examples or https://www.webhosting24.com/understanding-nginx-request_uri/ also explains it quite well.